# Label TapGesture doesn't fire Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was trying to add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to a `Label`.

```
 SliderAbout.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
 {
     Command = new Command(() => OpenAboutAppAsync()),
 });
```

SliderAbout is my `Label` which is set in Xaml and works correctly.

```
 <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="20,20,0,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label x:Name="SliderAbout" 
                           Text="Über die APP" 
                           Grid.Row="2"  
                           TextColor="White" 
                           FontFamily="Open Sans Light" 
                           FontSize="Medium"/>    
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
```

The code also gets run ( I put it in the class constructor)

**But the Method doesn't fire when I tap the label... Why won't it fire?**

Comment: Please show your layout. Is the label maybe underneath another element?

Comment: added xaml code

Comment: Either add the gesturerecognizer to the grid, or try `InputTransparent="true"` on the grid

Comment: It still wont work... i tried the exact hing with an image and it worked... but not with a label

Comment: check you Output window when you run. Does it say Cannot find Command or something like that?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis is right probably. Your layout is wrongly written. Correcting that may solve your issue. Try to removing grid and keeping simple label whether its working or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the gesture recognizer directly to the xaml and the action in the code behind or the view model if you're using mvvm approach. In your case it would be something like this:

```
<Label x:Name="SliderAbout" Text="Über die APP" Grid.Row="2"  TextColor="White" FontFamily="Open Sans Light" FontSize="Medium">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnLabelTapped" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

And in your code behind

```
private void OnLabelTapped (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here
}
```